# Adding a Line after a Certain Amount of Elements Displayed in Console

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int i = Array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            System.out.print(Array1[i] + " ");
}
```

Hi, how would I add a line after the 8th element displayed in the console?

```
6.7 3.4 6.7 1.2 ... 
(I need the rest of the elements after the 8th to be displayed on the next line here)
The sum of the array is: 18.0
```

Comment: Do you only want to add the line after the 8th element is displayed? Or is it every 8th element displayed (e.g. after 8th, after 16th, after 24th, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple check of the current index, and then print a new line when the index matches.

```
for (int i = Array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if ((i != Array1.length-1) && ((Array1.length - i - 1)%8 == 0)) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(Array1[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: `(i+1)%8` itself will skip the index `0`(first element)

Comment: Fixed based on the inputs. However, please note that the loop scan the array from back to front

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly... and the displaying from back to front is required in my assignment. Pointless but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length and index to print it:

```
for (int i = Array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if (Array1.length - i == 8) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(Array1[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using streams you can use the following: -

```
IntStream.range(0, Array1.length)
    .mapToObj( i -> Array1[i] + (i > 0 && i % 7 == 0 ? "\n": " "))
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```